# How to fix ripped laminate?

Tags: repair, flooring, vinyl-flooring, laminate-floor

We’re first time homeowners and there’s a rip/tear in the laminate flooring of the house we just bought (maybe it’s vinyl, I have no idea). There aren’t any extra panels left so replacing it would not be easy. Are there any fixes for this or is it literally replacing the whole panel?

Pics:

[image]

Comment: For temporary fix till it can be replaced, a bit of glue/adhesive squirted under the lifted part with some wax paper and a heavy weight on top.  Something like a  syringe to squirt or a tooth pick to spread.  Not sure of the best adhesive to use.  Temporary might be week or years.  A board of similar size from under something like a sofa/cabinet could be used for replacement.

Comment: @crip659 -  I'd call that an answer. I'd use PVA, diluted & injected using a blunt syringe you can pick up these days at any vape store. It will penetrate the wood/composite fibres quite well, for a longer-lasting repair than anything 'thicker'. Any that squeezes out will be easy to clean up afterwards. You can just about wipe it off with a damp cloth once it's dry but not fully cured.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Americans can be funny about syringes, while I can go in any store that sells farm stuff and pick up a handful

Comment: @crip659 shoot, you can walk into your local pharmacy and buy them off the shelf.